# Latex Compatibility with hyperref package

Tags: latex, compatibility, pdflatex

So, I've recently started using `LaTeX` but the problem is every time I view my generated `.pdf` file on a Mac, the boxes for links look quite "faint" and "incomplete" in places.

***I am using the following on Windows:***

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}

\usepackage[urlbordercolor={0 1 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{apacite}
```

Now this is due to the pdf viewer probably but I still wanted to ask:

Is there a universal setup for LaTeX generated `.pdf` files that works on both systems? Or what do you normally use to avoid this issue?

Left is Mac, Right is Windows:

[image: Left is Mac, Right is Windows]

Comment: Off-topic: `hyperref` should be loaded last (with only very few exceptions)

Comment: The pdf file will work on all systems, but not all pdf viewer will show the boxes. For example the mac default viewer `Preview` does not show them. If you want to make sure that also mac users will notice the links, you could use the `colorlinks` instead.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot to see what you mean with "faint boxes"?

Comment: added a screenshot now to the question, thx for the replies.